# Inserting an image into a cell

Tags: java, android

I am creating a maze and want to insert an image into one of the cells. I can use paint to insert and change the color of the cell, but I can not insert an image or even text. It seems cells only take paint. I would like to insert an image or text into the cell to show the Home or end location. The maze is random so the end cel can change.

Here is the java file I am using.

```
package com.example.mazegame;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;


public class GameView extends View{

    private Cell [] [] cells;
    private Cell player, exit;
    private static final int COLS=15, ROWS=15;
    private static final float WALL_THICKNESS =4;
    private float cellSize, hMargin, vMargin;
    private Paint wallPaint, startPaint, endPaint;
    public Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Random random;

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        wallPaint = new Paint();
        wallPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        wallPaint.setStrokeWidth(WALL_THICKNESS);
        startPaint = new Paint();
        startPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);


        endPaint = new Paint();
        endPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        random = new Random();
        canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wh);

        createMaze();
    }

    private Cell getNeighbor (Cell cell) {
        ArrayList <Cell> neighbors =new ArrayList<>();

        //left neighbor
        if (cell.col >0)
            if(!cells[cell.col-1][cell.row].visited)
                neighbors.add(cells[cell.col-1][cell.row]);
        //right neighbor
        if (cell.col < COLS-1)
            if(!cells[cell.col+1][cell.row].visited)
                neighbors.add(cells[cell.col+1][cell.row]);
        //top neighbor
        if (cell.row >0)
            if(!cells[cell.col][cell.row-1].visited)
                neighbors.add(cells[cell.col][cell.row-1]);
         //bottom neighbor
        if (cell.row <ROWS-1)
            if(!cells[cell.col][cell.row+1].visited)
                neighbors.add(cells[cell.col][cell.row+1]);

        if(neighbors.size()>0 ){
        int index = random.nextInt(neighbors.size());
        return neighbors.get(index);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void removeWall(Cell current, Cell next){
        if (current.col == next.col && current.row == next.row+1){
            current.topWall=false;
            next.bottomWall = false;
        }

        if (current.col == next.col && current.row == next.row-1){
            current.bottomWall=false;
            next.topWall = false;
        }

        if (current.col == next.col+1 && current.row == next.row){
            current.leftWall=false;
            next.rightWall = false;
        }

        if (current.col == next.col-1 && current.row == next.row){
            current.rightWall=false;
            next.leftWall = false;
        }
    }

    void createMaze() {
        Stack<Cell>stack = new Stack<>();
        Cell current, next;

        cells = new Cell [COLS] [ROWS];
        for (int x=0;x<COLS; x++) {
            for (int y=0;y<ROWS; y++){
                cells [x][y]=new Cell (x,y);
            }
        }
        player =cells [0][0];

        exit = cells [COLS-1][ROWS-1];


        current = cells [0][0];
        current.visited = true;
        do {
        next=getNeighbor (current);

        if (next !=null) {
            removeWall(current, next);
            stack.push(current);
            current = next;
            current.visited = true;
        }
        else
            current=stack.pop();
        }while (!stack.empty());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        int width=getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        if (width/height < COLS/ROWS)
            cellSize = width/(COLS +1);
        else
            cellSize=height/(ROWS+1);

        hMargin=(width-COLS*cellSize)/2;
        vMargin=(height-ROWS*cellSize)/2;

        canvas.translate(hMargin, vMargin);

        for (int x=0;x<COLS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
                if (cells[x][y].topWall)
                    canvas.drawLine(
                            x * cellSize,
                            y * cellSize,
                            (x + 1) * cellSize,
                            y * cellSize,
                            wallPaint);

                if (cells[x][y].leftWall)
                    canvas.drawLine(
                            x * cellSize,
                            y * cellSize,
                            x * cellSize,
                            (y + 1) * cellSize,
                            wallPaint);

                if (cells[x][y].rightWall)
                    canvas.drawLine(
                            (x + 1) * cellSize,
                            y * cellSize,
                            (x + 1) * cellSize,
                            (y + 1) * cellSize,
                            wallPaint);

                if (cells[x][y].bottomWall)
                    canvas.drawLine(
                            x * cellSize,
                            (y + 1) * cellSize,
                            (x + 1) * cellSize,
                            (y + 1) * cellSize,
                            wallPaint);


            }
        }
        float margin =cellSize/10;

    canvas.drawRect(
    player.col*cellSize+margin,
    player.row*cellSize+margin,
     (player.col+1)*cellSize-margin,
            (player.row+1)*cellSize-margin,
            startPaint);


        canvas.drawRect(

                exit.col*cellSize+margin,
                exit.row*cellSize+margin,
                (exit.col+1)*cellSize-margin,
                (exit.row+1)*cellSize-margin,
                endPaint);

    }

    private class Cell {
        boolean
        topWall = true,
        leftWall = true,
        bottomWall = true,
        rightWall = true,
        visited = false;

        int col, row;

        public Cell (int col, int row){
            this.col=col;
            this.row=row;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try creating an ImageView, then add a picture to it, and finally place that ImageView into your cell.

Comment: When trying to add an ImageView to a cell I receive an error Required type:
Paint
Provided:ImageView

Comment: By the way I have tried using the drawBitmap method, however I can place it on the canvas but not in a cell.

Comment: By the way I have tried using the drawBitmap method, however I can place it on the canvas but not in a cell.The maze will changes sizes and shapes. That is why I want to place the image into a cell. The last cell. That cell can be anywhere on the canvas, depending on the number of rows and columns. ```canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 200, 400, exitPaint);```